# Cambiar texto y color de un botón con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tengo estos botones, que los genero según la cantidad de registros (que traigo de una base de datos) con un `ng-repeat` de AngularJS, y quiero que al momento de poner el mouse encima pasen a ser verdes (como el botón `success` de bootstrap) y que en vez de "Lost" digan "Found". ¿Como podría hacer eso con jQuery? Ya he probado varias códigos de otros a ver si me funcionaban y no funcionaron.

Los botones:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aca les dejo la parte del index.html donde genero los botones:

```
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div id="mainContent" class="container-fluid">
    <!-- aca hay 2 section más antes de la lista -->
<!-- LIST OF MISSING DOGS -->
                <section id="view"  class="row row-content" ng-controller="MainController">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-7 well">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                            <h1>View the list of Missing Dogs</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="race" class="control-label col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1">Search by race: </label>
                                <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="race" type="text" required placeholder="Race of the dogs you are looking for" ng-model="query"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-responsive" ng-show="mascotas.length > 0 && mascotas != null">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Race</th>
                                            <th>Description</th>
                                            <th>Place</th>
                                            <th>¿Found?</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="mascota in mascotas | filter: {raza : query}">
                                            <td>{{ mascota.nombre }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ mascota.raza }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ mascota.descripcion }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ mascota.lugar }}</td>
                                            <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" ng-click="encontrado(mascota.id)"><span>Lost</span></button></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
        </div>
```

EDIT: Agrego el código que no me funcionó, creo que esta en JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').hover(function() {
            $(this).html('Found');
        }, function() {
            $(this).html('Lost'); 
        });
});
```

Comment: Por favor muéstranos al menos uno de los códigos que dices que has utilizado y que no han funcionado.

Comment: Me quedo el ultimo que utilice, ahora mismo lo agrego a la pregunta. Creo que esta en JavaScript, los demás los borre porque no me servían.

Comment: Bueno en realidad solo necesitas un :hover no necesita javascript si solo desea cambiar el fondo del boton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacer eso. Te propongo una alternativa dinámica con `data-hover`. Así, solo especifica el texto que quieres mostrar en `hover`.

**jQuery**

```js
$('.btn.lost').hover(onHover, onLeave);

function onHover() {
  $(this).removeClass('lost');
  $(this).addClass('found');
  $(this).text($(this).attr('on-hover'));
}
function onLeave() {
  $(this).removeClass('found');
  $(this).addClass('lost');
  $(this).text($(this).attr('on-leave'));
}
```

```css
.btn {
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: .5rem .9rem;
}
.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.btn.lost {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  border: 1px solid #e74c3c;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn.found {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  border: 1px solid #1abc9c;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <button class="btn lost" on-leave="Lost" on-hover="Found">Lost</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**AngularJS y CSS**

Ya que estás usando Angular, puedes hacer uso de `ng-mouseover` y `ng-mouseleave` para asignarle una clase en estos estados. Así mismo, para cambiar el texto **solo necesitas** atributos `data-` y referenciarlos mediante la propiedad CSS `content`.

```css
.btn {
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: .5rem .9rem;
  position: relative;
}
.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.btn.lost {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  border: 1px solid #e74c3c;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn.lost:after {
  content: attr(on-leave);
}
.btn.found {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  border: 1px solid #1abc9c;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn.found:after {
  content: attr(on-hover);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <button 
    class="btn lost"
    ng-class="{found: hover}" 
    ng-mouseenter="hover = true"
    ng-mouseleave="hover = false"
    on-hover="Found"
    on-leave="Lost"
  ></button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: La respuesta más completa, gracias por las opciones. Voy a probarlas y comento a ver como me fue. De todas formas, se podría hacer que no cambie el tamaño del botón??

Comment: El tamaño cambia por el tamaño del texto. Si le pones un ancho fijo en donde quepan ambos textos el tamaño no cambiará. También puedes hacer uso de `text-overflow: ellipsis;` y `white-space: nowrap;` para que se muestren puntos suspensivos.

Comment: Esta fue la única respuesta que me anduvo. De todas formas me surge una duda, ¿si le pongo un ancho fijo para que quepan las 2 palabras como hago para hacerlo responsive?

Comment: @AugustoHerbel El ancho de un botón por lo general no interfiere con el diseño responsivo. De hecho, cuando hacemos botones en móvil se tiende a agrandar (como que hacemos un zoom de la web) para que pueda verse bien.

Comment: Ahh bueno, genial entonces. Muchas gracias por la respuesta =D @Mitsu Gami

Answer (score 1):

Creo que con esto debería funcionar al sobreponer el puntero:

```
$('.btn').on('mouseenter',function(){
  $(this).removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-primary').find('span').text('found');
});
```

Esto funciona al salir el puntero:

```
$('.btn').on('mouseleave',function(){
  $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-danger').find('span').text('lost');
});
```

Lo primero que hago es editar el `css` del `button` para después cambiar el nombre de la etiqueta `span`.

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando con `jQuery`:

```js
$('.btn').on('mouseenter',function(){
      $(this).removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-primary').find('span').text('found');
    });

    $('.btn').on('mouseleave',function(){
      $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-danger').find('span').text('lost');
    });
```

```css
button{
  width:75px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn btn-danger'><span>lost</span></button>
<button class='btn btn-danger'><span>lost</span></button>
<button class='btn btn-danger'><span>lost</span></button>
```

Comment: Me gusta esta solución, solo que cambia el tamaño del botón y me gustaría que no cambie.

Comment: @AugustoHerbel le puedes predefinir un ancho ya sea directo desde `jquery` o desde css, incluso anidado con el atributo `style`, snippet editado

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr lo que quieres hacer, puedes usar la funcion `hover()` de jQuery para capturar los eventos cuando pasas el mouse por el botón y cuando sale del botón, lo que tienes que hacer es generar un id único para cada botón.

```js
$(".btn-danger").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css( "background-color", "#0f0");
    $( this ).text("Found");
  }, function() {
    $(this).css( "background-color", "#da4f49");
    $( this ).text("Lost");
  }
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Boton</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div id="mainContent" class="container-fluid">
    <!-- aca hay 2 section más antes de la lista -->
<!-- LIST OF MISSING DOGS -->
                <section id="view"  class="row row-content" ng-controller="MainController">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-7 well">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                            <h1>View the list of Missing Dogs</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="race" class="control-label col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1">Search by race: </label>
                                <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="race" type="text" required placeholder="Race of the dogs you are looking for" ng-model="query"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-responsive" ng-show="mascotas.length > 0 && mascotas != null">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Race</th>
                                            <th>Description</th>
                                            <th>Place</th>
                                            <th>¿Found?</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="mascota in mascotas | filter: {raza : query}">
                                            <td>{{ mascota.nombre }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ mascota.raza }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ mascota.descripcion }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ mascota.lugar }}</td>
                                            <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" ng-click="encontrado(mascota.id)" id="testbtn"><span>Lost</span></button></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
        </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Como te puedes dar cuenta he agregado un id al botón en este caso

```
id="testbtn"
```

Tú podrías hacer un id único con el id de las mascotas y hacer algo parecido.

Comment: Solamente pinta la mitad del botón de verde. La parte de abajo

Answer (score 1):

Ya tienes unas cuantas respuestas con JavaScript/jQuery, te voy a poner una que sólo necesita CSS sin necesidad de nada más.

La idea es usar `::after` (o `::before`) para cambiar el contenido del texto del botón, y aplicar los colores de la clase .btn-success cuando se pase el ratón (`:hover`) por encima del botón:

```css
.btn-danger span::after {
  content:"Lost";
}

.btn-danger:hover {
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#5cb85c !important;
  border-color:#4cae4c !important;
}

.btn-danger:hover span::after {
  content:"Found";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" ng-click="encontrado(mascota.id)"><span></span></button>
```

---

Explicación detallada ([como se pide en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25200/cambiar-texto-y-color-de-un-bot%C3%B3n-con-jquery/25222#comment40991_25222))

[`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::after) es un pseudo-elemento que correspondería a un último hijo virtual que tuviese el elemento al que se le añade. Y se usa para agregar contenido al final del elemento seleccionado. El valor que pongas en la propiedad `content` será el texto que se muestre.

Lo que hace esta solución es que elimina el texto de "Lost" y "Found" en el HTML y entonces lo añade a través del pseudo-elemento `::after`. En estado normal el texto será "Lost":

```
.btn-danger span::after {
  content:"Lost";
}
```

Ahora, cuando el ratón se pase por encima del botón queremos que el texto cambie a "Found". Para eso usamos la pseudo-clase [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:hover), que se presenta cuando el usuario pone el ratón encima del elemento. En este caso, cuando el usuario pone el ratón encima del botón `btn-danger` queremos que el `::after` cambie de valor, entonces eso se obtiene haciendo `.btn-danger:hover span::after`:

```
.btn-danger:hover span::after {
  content:"Found";
}
```

Por último, también queremos cambiar el color del botón cuando se pulse el ratón por encima y para eso también usamos el ya mencionado `:hover` (los colores correctos los he obtenido del CSS de Bootstrap):

```
.btn-danger:hover {
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#5cb85c !important;
  border-color:#4cae4c !important;
}
```

Espero haberlo explicado bien. Dime si necesitas ayuda comprendiendo algo.

Comment: Me encantó esta solución, por ser la más simple desde mi punto de vista, y porque hace exactamente lo que quiero sin tener que cambiar clases, ni nada en mi código original, solamente agregando CSS. De todas formas, me podrías explicar un poco más en detalle como funciona este código? Me sería de gran ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Ah y si puede ser, tengo otra duda que plantee en otra pregunta (http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25104/problema-con-plugin-affix-de-bootstrap), que me encantaría que la vieras si es posible, ya que no he tenido respuesta de nadie y de verdad necesito solucionarlo, es para una prueba de trabajo. Me sería de mucha ayuda. Muchas gracias @Alvaro Montoro

Comment: @AugustoHerbel he editado la respuesta para añadir una descripción más detallada. Espero que te ayude. Luego miro la otra pregunta, ahora ando algo ocupado